# Ionic hide sub header on scorlling

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am tryign to hide the subheader on scroll. In my directive I have the following code:

```
.directive('scrollWatch', function($rootScope) {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    var start = 0;
    var threshold = 150;

    elem.bind('scroll', function(e) {

      if(e.target.scrollTop - start > threshold) {
        $rootScope.slideHeader = true;
      } else {
        $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
      }
      if ($rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious >= e.target.scrollTop - start) {
        $rootScope.slideHeader = false;
      }
      $rootScope.slideHeaderPrevious = e.target.scrollTop - start;
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });
  };

})
```

and in my page.html:

```
<ion-view title="Job Post " id="page8"  hide-nav-bar="true" class="bar-positive " hide-back-button="false"  ng-class="{'bar-subheader-slide-away': slideHeader}" >

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Sub Header Show/Hide on Scroll</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-subheader bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Hide this sub header on scroll down and display on scroll up!</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>


    <ion-content padding="false" class="has-footer" id="jobdetailsWrapper"  scroll-watch>



    <a class="item" href="#">
    List Item
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="#">
    List Item
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="#">
    List Item
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="#">
    List Item
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="#">
    List Item
    </a>
    <a class="item" href="#">
    List Item
    </a>

    </ion-content>


</ion-view>
```

But nothing happens. The sub header stays there and I don't get any errors. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

these example or codepen works on ionic 1.0 beta. So if you are working in ionic v1.3.2 "france". Use the next steps:

**delegate-handle(name) and on-scroll(function)**

```
<ion-content on-scroll="getScrollPosition()" delegate-handle="mainScroll">...</ion-content>
```

**add ng-class in ion-nav-bar**

```
<ion-nav-bar ng-class="{'hide-header': slideHeader}">...</ion-nav-bar>
```

**Add action to *slideHeader***

```
$scope.posAnt = 0;
$scope.getScrollPosition = function(){
  var pos = $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').getScrollPosition().top;
  if(pos < $scope.posAnt){
    $scope.slideHeader = false;
  }else{
    $scope.slideHeader = true;
  }
  $scope.posAnt = pos;
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

Now just add css to the class hide-header.

**Example**

```
.hide-header .bar-header{
    display: none;
}
```

Tip: Remenber to use the platform system(ios, android) as you want.

```
.platform-android .hide-header .bar-header
.platform-ios .hide-header .bar-header
```

The function getScrollPosition works similar to Youtube app for android 6.0. So when you scroll-down bar-header hides and and when you scroll-up bar-header shows.

Change getScrollPsotion as you need.

Good luck.